# Get list of events from MySQL that aren't blocked in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've come to the point where I need what seems a really overly-complex query in MySQL. Basically, I have one table which is a list of events:

```
eventid | businessid | category | type | subtype | start | end
```

Getting the events within a specified time is easy. BUT, the users can also block events from showing using the businessid, category, type or subtype fields. These are listed in the "blocked" table...

```
userid | businessid | category | type | subtype
```

This table will just list their user ID with information in the item blocked

```
00001 | b00001 | null | null | null
00001 | null | nightlife | null | null
```

and so forth...

Originally I had thought I could maybe use a join to get the information, but since there are multiple categories, this isn't going to work. I guess I could make an array of each type of block and test the query against this on each iteration, but it seems like there should be a way to work it into the query itself. Any ideas? Thanks for any help guys.

** NOTE: I can change the layout of the tables if needed.

Comment: Maybe take a look at mysql `IF` statement

Comment: Could you clarify how the `blocked` table is meant to work? Does an `event` row need to match every non `NULL` column in `blocked` to be considered blacklisted?

Comment: In the rest of the program, the user is able to see the businesses that are associated with the events. These are broken down into categories, types and subtypes(Nightlife, Bar, Karaoke/Dining, restaurant, chinese/Fitness, Gym, Yoga/etc). The user can choose what they want to see by blocking a particular business(by businessid), or a whole category/type/subtype as they see fit. When they block something, it is added to the blocked table with(so if they were to block a specific business, it would be `00001 | b00001 | null | null | null`

Comment: If they later block Karaoke bars, then a new entry would be added `00001 | null | null | null | karaoke`. So, when I pull the list of events, it should filter out those "blocked" items, and the returned row should contain only those the user actually wants to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just create a `NOT EXISTS` clause using a predicate of *any* matching rows in `blocked`.

```
SELECT e.* FROM `events` e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `blocked` b
    WHERE b.userid = :user_id -- this is a parameter for the user ID
    AND (
        e.businessid = b.businessid
        OR e.category = b.category
        OR e.type = b.type
        OR e.subtype = b.subtype
    )
)
```

Comment: What if a user only wants to block a combination i.e. business_id b00001 and nightlife? It seems that the author wants to block specific combinations because the example has separate rows for the same user.

Comment: @FuzzyTree OP would need to clarify how the `blocked` table is supposed to work. I'm working on the assumption that any column value in the `blocked` table acts as a blacklist for that value

Comment: I tried to clarify some with my comment above. But yes, there will be multiple "blacklists" (each row for the userid in blocked table). Also, it is possible that the user has blocked nothing, and therefore there would be no entries in blocked...if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You want a complete match except where columns are null. So I think this should work.

```
select * from events e
where not exists (
    select * from blocked b 
    where b.user_id = ?
    and (
        (b.business_id = e.business_id OR b.business_id IS NULL)
        AND (b.category = e.category OR b.category IS NULL)
        AND (b.type = e.type OR b.type IS NULL)
        AND (b.subtype = e.subtype OR b.subtype IS NULL)
        AND (
            b.business_id IS NOT NULL 
            OR b.category IS NOT NULL 
            OR b.type IS NOT NULL 
            OR b.subtype IS NOT NULL
        )
    )
)
```